# How to delete all words in a file that contains at least one number in shell script using 'sed'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
for i
    do
sed "s/[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]//g" $i
done
```

The code above works fine, except if the word begins with a number.

Comment: do add some sample words that should be deleted and words that shouldn't be deleted.. that way it would be clearer as well as provide testing ground for answers... you probably need `[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: To expand on what @Sundeep said, [edit] your question to provide us with a sample of one of your input files and the corresponding output from that file.

Comment: Thank you @Sundeep, it works!

Comment: Do you also want to delete a word with only digits ? And a word like `this1has2digits`?